# How do I force Propel to use a CROSS JOIN in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, propel

So ironically, I had an issue where I was [getting unwanted CROSS JOINs in my query](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/propel-users/KJCQhVV1WM8), but now, I need to build a query with a CROSS JOIN! I've been searching and testing for the past couple of hours, but I haven't been able to replicate it. Can anyone else do this in Propel?

Comment: One quick way of doing this is to build a view containing the non-standard join you want, and then add the view to your schema. There's probably a nicer way to do it, but it will get you going quickly, and you can fix it later if you wish.

Comment: I was working off a client's database, so I don't think I can create a view.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have server permissions to do so, or that they won't agree to its creation? As a developer you should have full rein to create what you need, and if they need to audit it, so be it: it's hardly a dramatic change.

Comment: The latter. End of the day we just created a custom query and ran it through PropelPDO. It just angers me that when I was _debugging_ Propel, I would always get `CROSS JOIN`s when I coded it wrong. Now that I want `CROSS JOIN`s, I can't replicate it.

Comment: Yeah, frustrating. I'd play around with `addJoin()` with a condition of `1=1` or something like that, either in a `Criteria` or a `ModelCriteria` - as far as I know `CROSS JOIN` is just a Cartesian product, and thus does not need to be explicitly declared as a join (you can just do `FROM table1,table2` without any old-style `WHERE` clauses).